# pg_restore, violates foreign key constraint restoring to RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pg-restore

Been trying to restore a dump into a AWS RDS instance.
No matter what I try I end up with the same error type.

```
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "sample": ERROR:  insert or update on table "sample" violates foreign key constraint "sample_ratio_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (ratio_id)=(1433) is not present in table "ratio".
```

This happens as the table `ratio` hasn't been restored yet.

I have tried disabling the triggers using `pg_restore --disable-triggers -S postgres` but I receive a permission denied.

```
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 6256; 0 18996 TABLE DATA sample
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_26462" is a system trigger
        Command was: ALTER TABLE sample DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

Looking into the database, the user `postgres` does not have `superuser` privileges, the one that have them is `rdsadmin` but I dont have (and i think i shouldn't have) access to it.

How should I restore the data? Is there a way to overcome the constraints while using pg_restore on a AWS RDS instance?

Comment: If you were doing the restore into an empty database this shouldn't be a problem.  If you are not restoring into an empty database, then what are you doing?  Which options are you giving to restore, and what is the pre-existing state of the database?

Comment: Perhaps the original database had data corruption. In that case, you have to clean up manually before you can create the constraint.